# CSS selector or HTML parser for go?

Tags: html, css, go

Is there anything like fizzler, htmlagilitypack or beautifulsoup for go?

I want to do something like `doc.load(html); aelements:=doc.SelectAll("a")` in go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two that I know of:

- http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-html-transform/css/selector is one.
- https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery is another

go-html-transform also comes with some tools to transform the html that matches selectors.